# How to delay a C++ command on Mac OS X

Tags: c++, macos

I'm working on this very simple OS with Netbeans on Mac and I need to delay a line of code for a timer application. Is there a simple command I can use to delay (do nothing/wait) for a certain amount of time? I've looked on other questions on this topic and they say to type "Thread.Sleep(1000);" but that just comes up with a bunch of errors. Thanks for your help in advance!

I tried using one of the suggestions below and got this:

main.cpp:29:26: error: expected namespace name
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
                    ~~~~~^
main.cpp:30:10: error: no member named 'this_thread' in namespace 'std'
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(5s);
    ~~~~~^
main.cpp:30:34: error: invalid suffix 's' on integer constant
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(5s);
                                 ^
3 errors generated.

Comment: What is C++ command? This invented term introduces ambiguity into your question.

Comment: Using sleep is almost always a sign of improper coding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a portable solution and you have at least C++11 suport then you can use [`std::this_thread::sleep_for`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) like

```
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
```

This will cause the current thread to sleep for 1 second.

Answer (score 1):

since you are on mac you can use

```
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

usleep(1000000);
```

This will make the program wait one second.